# if shipping address is <= 20km from store address woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to find a solution to create a condition that checks whether the address (billing or shipping) is within 20km from the store address to enable free shipping.

```
if ($checkout_fields['billing'] != $address) { //variable to save store address
   unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );
}
```

Free shipping can be achieved in woocommerce settings yes, but I need to check whether the customer is within 20km from the depot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to fall back to a geocoding API to do things like that. One possibility is fall back to Google Maps API. Some time ago i had a similar problem and solved it by using this snippet:

```
    function getDistancebetween($clientadress, $shopadress){

    $clientadress = str_replace(' ','+',$clientadress);
    $shopadress = str_replace(' ','+',$shopadress);

    $geo_shop = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$clientadress.'&sensor=false');
    $json_shop = json_decode($geo_shop);

    $geo_adress = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$shopadress.'&sensor=false');
    $json_client = json_decode($geo_adress);

    $latitude_shop = $json_shop->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude_shop = $json_shop->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    $latitude_client = $json_client->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude_client = $json_client->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    $theta = $longitude_shop - $longitude_client;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($latitude_shop)) * sin(deg2rad($latitude_client)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitude_shop)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude_client)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    return $dist * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.6093;

}
```

R Version can be found at: https://web.stanford.edu/~eready/distance.html